# Swap button behaviour to another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, slick.js

So I'm using SlickSlider (http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), and I'm trying to use the Next and Prev buttons with other elements (spans in another container).

I've tried:

```
$('button.next').click(function(){      
    $('#idOfMySpanElement').slick('slickPrev');
});
```

And:

```
$('#idOfMySpanElement').slick('slickPrev');
```

Nut no luck. I've tried other things too but I don't even remember.

When using the second method it throughs an error:  Cannot read property 'slickPrev' of undefined(…)

So I was thinking... is there a way to "get" the behaviour of the original buttons and swap them manually to the spans?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to call next/prev slide from outside the slider ?

If so then try:

```
$('.what_you_are_clicking_on').click(function(){
    $('.this_is_your_slick_slider').slick('slickPrev');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the **button.next** contained inside **#idOfMySpanElement** to go to the prev slick element you need to change your handler:

```
    $('#idOfMySpanElement button.next').click(function(){
        $('slickSelector').slick('slickPrev');
    });
```